# Increase execution speed for web scraping with for loops

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, web-scraping

The following code performs a web scraping at a travel company, where for each origin and destination are detailed the bus lines that make the trip. The idea is to put together a table with all the rows and companies they perform.
The code itself works and fulfills its goal. However, I need to perform this search for a list of about 650 cities.
I left the code running for about 3 hours and he held less than 5% of the cities.
Any suggestions on how I can improve performance in this code?

```
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)
library(rjson)
library(dplyr)


#LOAD LIST OF CITYS
cidades <- jsonlite::fromJSON("Listas Cidades Artesp.json")
empresasXlinhas <- data.frame()

#RCURL PARAMETRES
headers = c(
  "Accept" = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
  "Accept-Language" = "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  "Connection" = "keep-alive",
  "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  "Cookie" = "__RequestVerificationToken_L1RyYW5zcG9ydGVDb2xldGl2bw2=tY-yKlWmbZvAJzMHmITkohPiIos5XkjDBwf1ZBfP_bYWdXJMBF2Qw3z_B-LRVo0kXjdnHqDqsbZ04Zij_PM-wAf4DWVKfnQskOhqo4ANSRc1",
  "Origin" = "http://extranet.artesp.sp.gov.br",
  "Referer" = "http://extranet.artesp.sp.gov.br/TransporteColetivo/OrigemDestino?fbclid=IwAR3_hZwajHk_iyU085S1LDTqLCOYLHIZ5K825XgPGcB4tMI0EuCJpQNrJHM",
  "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"
)

#WEB SCRAPING
for (x in cidades$Codigo){
  for (y in cidades$Codigo){
    
    if (x != y){
      params = paste("origem=",x,"&destino=",y,"&__RequestVerificationToken=Z-wXmGOb9pnQbmkfcQXmChT-6uc3YfGjftHwK4HnC9SDCaKmzIafo7AI3lChBY6YDBHdpT_X98mSHGAr_YrTNgKiepKxKraGu7p6PI7dV4g1", sep ="")
      res <- postForm("http://extranet.artesp.sp.gov.br/TransporteColetivo/OrigemDestino/GetGrid", .opts=list(postfields = params, httpheader = headers, followlocation = TRUE), style = "httppost")
      if (res != "[]"){
        print(paste(x,y))
        empresa <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res)[[2]]
        empresa <- empresa %>% mutate(cod_origem = x, cod_destino = y)
        empresasXlinhas <- rbind(empresasXlinhas, empresa)
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give example of `cidades` ?

Comment: While I first suspected the nested loop, replacing it with a vectorized version only brought a negligible speed increase - up to the harvesting part which I skipped for lack of postcodes. It might well be that the server throttles or caps automated requests: in that case, there's not much to do from your side.

Comment: To extend what I_O mention, do not perform `rbind()` inside the loop, this is a very slow operation when the data structure becomes large.  It is much better to preallocate the space and then assign the values to a vector/data frame.

Comment: @minem, is a city list. Each city is represented by a 3-digit number. For example, 100 - São Paulo; 244 - Campinas and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to the list of cities, so I cannot run the code to check how fast it is.

Some high level considerations: Instead of downloading and aggregating in the same loop, I suggest you first download everything and later read the data. This allows you to stop your script without having to start from scratch, but instead pick up where you left.

If you want to make async calls consider the {httr2} package. Alternatively, consider rolling your own "download" function and use the {furrr} like this (please forgive my shortening of the long lines -- I think this makes it a clearer read and it is just copying your code):

First, make a dataframe/tibble of the missing files:

```r
all_input <- tidyr::crossing(
    origin = cidades$Codigo,
    destination = cidades$Codigo
) %>%
    mutate(
        filename = <some reasonable filename>
    ) %>%
    filter(
        origin != destination,
        !fs::file_exists(filename)
    )
```

The filename column could for example be

```r
fs::path("raw_data", paste(origin, destination, sep = "_"), ext = "csv")
```

Then make a function that downloads and saves each response

```r
my_download_func <- function(origin, destination, filename) 
{
    headers <- c(...)
    params <- paste("origem=", origin, "&destino=", destination, ...)
    res <- postForm(...)
    empresa <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res)[[2]]
    readr::write_csv(empresa, filename)
}
```

Finally, go through the rows of `all_input` in parallel with {furrr}

```r
future::plan(future::multisession)
furrr::pwalk(all_input, my_download_func)
```

One final piece of advice is to consider some error handling when parsing `res`.